# Saving special characters in php

Tags: php, html, ascii, special-characters

I've been reading for hours and I can't wrap my head completely around the encoding problem. 
I am using PHP
Specifying charset=utf-8.
I want to be able to input certain characters e.g. the bullet • and the arrow ⇒ into a textarea.
I save directly to an mySQL Database and the symbols are correctly stored there.
To display the saved text from the database, I call the following function to translate the stored symbols for the textarea.

```
function htmlspecialchars2($string, $flags=ENT_NOQUOTES){
$string = htmlspecialchars($string, $flags);    // to help prevent code injection
$string = str_replace(chr(149), "&#8226", $string);  // converts bullet to html
$string = str_replace("⇒", "&#8658",$string);   // don't know the ascii code for the arrow
return $string;
}
```

This works for the bullet but not for the arrow. Any suggestions how to save (and then re-display) extended HTML characters. I've read everything I can find, but am missing something.

Comment: Why aren't you just using the charset parameter for htmlspecialchars ?

Comment: try `utf8_decode()`??

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). That should convert all characters that have HTML character entity equivalents into HTML entities (to reverse that use [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)).

---

PS: on my system, `htmlentities('⇒', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')` returns `&rArr;`

Comment: when I use $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), the textarea is blank. If I use the code you have above (only the arrow) it will show the arrow.

Comment: <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>
</pre> ---Without the 'UTF-8' parameter, it displays all the text but with the arrow as a �

Comment: You're probably altering the UTF-8 string before passing it to `htmlentities`

Comment: I've double checked - the string comes straight from the database, whose column is utf8_general_ci (although the table for some strange reason is in latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: Use [`mb_detect_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) on it, and see what it prints

Comment: It is ASCII (I was just about to figure out how to do that..thanks).

Comment: Well, that's not good. A dirty solution would be to store the entity-encoded string in the db (run `htmlentities` on input). Otherwise you'll have to locate and fix the encoding issues

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that follows, the solution had 2 parts

1) htmlentities was needed as mentioned by One Trick Pony (thank you!) and that was the real answer.

2) However, the other half was needing to explicitly set the encoding for the session.
    mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");

Note: the new code is much simpler. Instead of calling a special function htmlspecialchars2() as shown above, I can simply call htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8')